# Adapter remove doesn't work

Tags: android, sqlite

I tried to remove the  item from a custom adapter and notify that data has been changed. But this seems not work.

```
mListDataAdapter.remove(mListDataAdapter.getItem(position));
mListDataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Neither works `mListDataAdapter.clear();` No changes to adapter in debugging mode.

My activity extends `AppCompatActivity` if this helps. I call this code inside `onActionItemClicked`. At the same time I call delete from database, which works correct.

Update.
Here is ListDataAdapter:

```
public class ListDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

List list = new ArrayList();


public ListDataAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
}

static class LayoutHandler{
TextView id_;
TextView title;

}


@Override
public void add(Object object) {
    super.add(object);
    list.add(object);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = convertView;
    LayoutHandler layoutHandler;

    if(row == null){

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.todo_row_layout,parent,false);

        layoutHandler = new LayoutHandler();
        layoutHandler.id_ = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.id_);
        layoutHandler.title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.todoTitle);
        row.setTag(layoutHandler);
    } else {
        layoutHandler = (LayoutHandler) row.getTag();

    }

        DataProvider dataProvider = (DataProvider) this.getItem(position);
        layoutHandler.title.setText(dataProvider.getTitle());
        layoutHandler.id_.setText(String.valueOf(dataProvider.getId_()));

    return row;

   // return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
}
```

}

Comment: Please update your question with your CustomAdapter or remove method source to help to you out in better way.

Comment: Please upload the complete code and logcat. This part seems fine.

Comment: Updated with adapter code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Adapter, define remove function

```
public void remove(int position)
{
    list.remove(position);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
public void remove(Object object)
{
    list.remove(object);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

When you want to remove once, call mListDataAdapter.remove(position) or mListDataAdapter.remove(object)

Comment: Worked after I refreshed cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Use following remove functions in your CustomAdapter class : Considering mList as ArrayList of your data objects in CustomAdapter.

```
    public void remove(CustomObject msg ){
                mlist.remove(msg);
                notifyDataSetChanged(); 
    }

    public void remove(int ID){

            int size = mlist.size()-1;
            for(int i=size; i>=0; i--){
                if( mlist.get(i).getId() == ID)     {
                        mlist.remove(i);
                        break;
                }
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged(); 

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

when you `remove/add/change` your data you should make it with data model in your `adapter` and then `notified` for the `adapter`. In your case I suggest as below, :

In your `adapter` class, create a method to remove data:

`public void remove(Object obj) {
        this.list.remove(obj);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
//by call this you should not to call adapter.notifyDataSetChange()
    }`